# Why does nodejs debugger ignore breakpoints when it's run in npm configuration?

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm, webstorm

I have a node.js code in WebStorm. I debug the code by using node.js configuration and it works fine.

However, once I run debug mode in npm configuration, WebStorm ignores the breakpoints. I tried to add the variables "--debug" and "--debug-brk" to 'Arguments' field and it still didn't solve the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out this tutorial: http://pavelpolyakov.com/2016/05/01/webstorm-npm-tasks-debug/
You need to add $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION in your npm script.
Here's the [original issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18581) on the WebStorm tracker.

Comment: With Node v8.10.0 and Mac OS 10.13.6 and chrome 69 I can't get it working given the hints https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/run-debug-configuration-npm.html and https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/01/how-to-debug-with-webstorm/

Comment: Please provide a bit more details about the error you get. You can contact the WebStorm tech support using this form: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Answer (score 0):

You need to add $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION (or %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION% on Windows) in your npm script. Please note that `NODE_DEBUG_OPTION` should be placed right after `node`, where node parameters are expected, for example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION ./bin/www"
  }
```